# Angular template of template

Tags: angular, templates

I would like to know if it is possible in Angular to have an identical left menu for all the components of the same top menu and another different for all the other components of this other top menu (example image)

Thank you for your help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Fgv.png)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Questions like these will be closed unless supported by some article and code which reflects your effort before posting it.  Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the left menu is a module that must be displayed only for the pages corresponding to the top menu.

Example :
For the top "Administration" menu, all the pages (components) must have the left menu (module) containing the "Administration" submenu with all the links to the "Administration" pages.